# MFC error like A reference that is not to 'const' cannot be bound to a non-lvalue

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, mfc

I want to use `CList` of MFC class for both a static value and dynamic value.
I guess `&d1` is pointer to `d1` value, so there shouldn't be a error, but there is.
I understand the error is from the difference between `const` or not and it couldn't be l-value. But I want to use it as a entry of `CList<DATA*, DATA*&>`.

**Error:**

```
error C2664: 'struct __POSITION *__thiscall CList<struct DATA *,struct DATA 
* &>::AddTail(struct DATA *& )' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'struct 
DATA *' to 'struct DATA *& '
```

Then I could show this simply like below.
Is there another way to avoid this error?
Thanks in advance.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <afxtempl.h>

struct DATA
{
    int n;
    CString id;
    CString time;
};

DATA d1;
int main()
{
    CList<DATA*, DATA*&> list2;

    d1.n = 1;

    //error here
    list2.AddTail((DATA*)&d1);

    //no error
    DATA* pd1;
    pd1 = &d1;
    list2.AddTail(pd1);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Storing the address of a variable with automatic storage is poor design and likely to cause problems (like when `d1` goes out of scope).

Comment: Why are you casting a `DATA*` to `DATA*`?

Comment: You do a no-op cast at `list2.AddTail((DATA*)&d1);`

Comment: Above code is so simple code to show this error. I just want to save a fixed memory such as static area or automatic area in CList made for dynamic memory. Of course, I will these entry would not be wound while CList is holding them.

Comment: Yes, without the casting, I have a same error. list2.AddTail(&d1);

Comment: I modified above code to move declaration of d1 from automatic variable to global variable, of course it is not much important anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> struct DATA
> {
>     int n;
>     CString id;
>     CString time;
> };
>
> ...
>     CList<DATA*, DATA*&> list2;
> ```

I think you are using `CList` wrong. What you probably should do is:

```
CList<DATA> myList;

// Create and populate your data...
DATA d1;
d1.n = 1;
...

// Add new node to the list
myList.AddTail(d1);
```

Note the simpler syntax `CList<DATA>`. The linked-list is made by nodes with embedded `DATA` objects. Why do you need another indirection with nodes containing *pointers* to `DATA` objects? This is less cache-friendly (following those pointed-to data) and more inefficient.

Note also that if you simply use `CList<DATA>`, the second template argument `ARG_TYPE` is correctly deduced to be `const DATA&` by default, as per `CList` template declaration (`TYPE = DATA`, `ARG_TYPE = const DATA&`):

> ```
> template<class TYPE, class ARG_TYPE = const TYPE&>
> class CList : public CObject
> ```

---

**EDIT**

If you really want to store *pointers* to `DATA` in your `CList` nodes, then you can do something like this:

```
CList<DATA*> myPtrList;

DATA d1;
d1.n = 1;
...

myPtrList.AddTail(&d1);
```

Comment: Thank you, I know what you point, but in case of the DATA's size is too big, so it should need certain memory management. then a way like pre-allocation of them and assigning each one would be needed.

Comment: Of course, chaning CList<DATA*,DATA*&> to CList<DATA*,DATA*> could solve this issue, but I just want to know using CList<DATA*,DATA*&>, is there another way to avoid this error.

Comment: @semenbari I added an edit with list nodes containing _pointers_ to DATAs.

Comment: @semenbari You don't need to complicate your code and introduce bugs with an explicit definition of `ARG_TYPE`. Just use  `CList<DATA*>` and accept the default for `ARG_TYPE`.